# Loop function to run 25 times but at 2 second interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function to open an iframe , i need to run this function 25 times and open 25 iframes with different url parameter paths.

After the function is ran , i will get some content , then close the iframe , then reopen a new iframe using a url with the next parameter of "SEQNO=100" , to 101 , 102 etc all the way to 124.

How can i get this to work , i tried setting a loop but it opened all frames at same time

```
function backupMSG() {

    // OPEN NEW IFRAME EACH TIME FUNCTION RUNS - ITERATE "SEQNO=100 to SEQNO+125"
    $('body').append("<iframe src='" + baseURLDynamic + "/" + year + "/csetup?L=" + league_id + "&C=HMPGMSG&SEQNO=100&PRINTER=1' id='iframe'></iframe>");
    $('body').append("<iframe src='" + baseURLDynamic + "/" + year + "/csetup?L=" + league_id + "&C=HMPGMSG&SEQNO=101&PRINTER=1' id='iframe'></iframe>");
    $('body').append("<iframe src='" + baseURLDynamic + "/" + year + "/csetup?L=" + league_id + "&C=HMPGMSG&SEQNO=102&PRINTER=1' id='iframe'></iframe>");
    // posted 3 urls for example - need to loop over 25 different parameters

    $("#iframe").on("load", function () {
        // Get some content from iframe
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Ran 1 Time") // COUNT HOW MANY TIMES HAS THIS FUNCTION RAN
            $("#iframe").remove();
        }, 600);
        setTimeout(function () {
            backupMSG(); //RUN FUNCTION 25 TIMES AT INTERVAL OF 2 SECONDS
        }, 2000);
    });

}
```

I tried loops like below but both result in console log of all 25 at same time and i want a delay before it loops through the function again

```
n=25;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hi!"+i)
    }, 2000);
}

n=25;
setTimeout(function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        console.log("Hi!"+i)
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Do you actually want a 2 second interval, or do you want the time is takes for the iframe to load + 2 seconds? Your current approach is going to do the latter. (Also, if you use duplicate IDs, you will have problems)

Comment: after 1st iframe loads , i want to wait 2 seconds , then run the function again in 2 seconds and do that 25 times

Comment: Use an external variable, increase it by one, then add a single iframe using the variable as SEQNO parameter (or use a single iframe and simply set its src)

Comment: please demonstrate thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function backupMSG(id) {
  $("body").append(
    "<iframe src='https://picsum.photos/id/" +
      id +
      "/200/300' id='iframe'></iframe>"
  );

  $("#iframe").on("load", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("Run " + id + " Time");
      $("#iframe").remove();
    }, 600);
  });
}

let startId = 1;
let count = 3;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (startId >= count) clearInterval(interval)
  backupMSG(startId);
  startId++;
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var i=1,n=25;
setInterval(function(){
    if(i<=n){
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    }else{
        clearInterval();
    }
},2000)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.